# OpenFileDialog cannot read images

Tags: c#, wpf

When I use OpenFileDialog to select a file on my WPF project I got an error window saying:

> You do not have permissions to open this file.
>
> Request permissions from the file owner or an administrator.

This only happen when I use image format files, with other type of file the File Dialog work as intended.

I already tried to open the app as admin and the error persists.

Test code:

```
  OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
  fileDialog.Filter = "jpg |*.jpg|png |*.png";
  fileDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Try changing your `Filter` string to this: `fileDialog.Filter = "Images (*.jpg; *.png)|*.png,*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*";` - I understand it can be finnicky about whitespace (also are you really sure you want separate filters for each file-type and not have an "All images" option?)

Comment: @Dai When I select the folder with images shows empty, and with the option All files I get the same error.

Comment: Where and how is the error being displayed, exactly? Is it an `Exception`? A message-box displayed on-screen by the File Dialog itself? Do you actually have permission to open that image file? (check your NTFS ACLs) Is the image on a network share (if so, check your SMB ACLs in addition to the NTFS ACLs)?

Comment: @Dai It doesn't throw any exception is a message box from the FileDialog, and I have permision to open the file. It is on my PC on my documents and I can open other files that aren't images without any problem.

Comment: Are you using WinForms' `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` in a WPF project? Or is this a different `OpenFileDialog` class?

Comment: I tried with 2 different libraries: `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` and `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try a new way which is safe at finding what file types you are looking for:

```
var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
{
    Title = "Select an Image",
    Filter = "Images |*.jpg; *.png",
    CheckFileExists = true
};

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    
}
```

On file permissions try this https://windowsreport.com/no-permission-open-file/

Comment: your issue may be with the files themselves please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, not exactly fix the problem but the program can load images from different locations for some reazon, I move the files to _my images_ folder and it work

Comment: welcome, sometime these issues are not easy to fix at ago. glad to have helped